# Content LiveKernel Minidump / GUI

Tags: windows, privacy, gui, minidumps

I ve just noticed that WER (Windows Error Reporting) creates a lot of small mindiumps (about 300kb) even without getting a BSOD. Recent crashes were only caused by my graphics driver. As the mindumps are automatically send to Microsoft, i am not very happy with this. Concerning the privacy aspect, do you think there is a realistic chance that the minidump contents the actual visual content of my screen (of cours inly parts of it due the dump size).

e.g. i write a document, and because the GUI is handeled by the graphics driver, some Text, Passwords, Images etc. are in the kernel RAM/framebuffer an so partly in the minidump?

I tried to find this out myself, but to be honest I just lack necessary knowledge. There are a lot of relevant options regarding WER minidumps (e.g. include referenced heap memory) an so on, but I am still confused with this...